# Есть ли достойные альтернативы для фильтрации html кроме htmlpurifier.org

Tags: php, html

На сайте есть модуль статей, перед сохранением html текста статьи нужно удалять лишнии теги, лишнии атрибуты, преобразовывавать переносы строк в br, преобразовывать ссылки в html.

Сейчас использую библиотеку htmlpurifier.org, но она весьма странно работает, не всегда как нужно, есть ли достойные альтернативные библиотеки?

**Решение:**

Выбрал Jevix для себя. Он оказался самым лучшим решением. Брал не из официального репозитория, а из livestreet. Там есть дополнительные методы.

https://github.com/livestreet/livestreet-framework/blob/master/libs/vendor/Jevix/jevix.class.php

Comment: Если уж просите совет в выборе более подходящих инструментов и библиотек, то указывайте, что именно вы не смогли решить с помощью выбранного вами инструмента или библиотеки, на какие именно проблемы наткнулись, как попытались решить и т. п. Вопросы без явных критериев, просто с просьбами "дайте что-нибудь" являются оффтопиком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [kses - PHP HTML/XHTML filter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kses/). Давно вроде не обновлялся, в каком состоянии сейчас - не знаю.
- [htmLawed: PHP code to purify & filter HTML](http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/). Вполне живой проект.
- [Jevix](http://jevix.ru/project/). Есть PHP и Perl версии. Давно не обновлялся, особенно PHP-часть. Но вполне работает ([примеры](https://github.com/ur001/Jevix/)).

Comment: посмотрю в сторону Jevix, у htmLawed больно код страшный. спасибо

Comment: Если не смущает это, конечно :-) "*Автор больше не развивает проект, перешёл на Python и постепенно забывает синтаксис PHP*"

Comment: смущает, но все равно прикручу к проекту, посмотрю как работает по сравнению с htmlpurifier

Comment: @klopp Это для хороших программистов на PHP характерно...